# Ensuring body height does not exceed browser height

Tags: html, css

So essentially at present, I am trying to make it so the body's height never exceeds the height of the browser (E.G. there is no need for a scroll bar) as I only require my content area (which is set to I believe the div class content) to be the scrollable section.

Now I can view it on one screen size and get it looking just right by setting that content area to have I believe 70vh. But then on another screen size that same 70vh will either be smaller or larger (and thus exceed the browser's height). And I've tried setting like 100vh to the body and html and it just does nothing.

Desired result on all screens: 
[image]

Current result on some screens: 
[image]

index.html is located here: https://github.com/ashworthian/stprecious/blob/master/index.html

css is located here: https://github.com/ashworthian/stprecious/blob/master/css/style.css

And yes I know I need to clean my css up but just trying to get this height thing fixed first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)

Comment: can you provide code of that ?

Comment: Hi, can you provide a bit of context? like showing some code, testing environment etc... sometimes there are some quirks with vw/vh and it's impossible to guess without knowing more :)

Comment: index.html is located here: https://github.com/ashworthian/stprecious/blob/master/index.html

css is located here: https://github.com/ashworthian/stprecious/blob/master/css/style.css

And yes I know I need to clean my css up but just trying to get this height thing fixed first.

Comment: If anything you should share your code in a snippet to reproduce your issue in the question, not link to an external repo

Comment: I would do that if I knew how since I'm still relatively new to coding webpages, hence why I simply linked the files as they are hosted currently.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need to adjust this to your code; but the basic idea is the following:

By using **Flexbox**; you can define a flex-container which will encapsulate the content of the page; you set this container to have a `flex-direction: column`, so it positions the elments inside vertically.

After that, you have to tell the section that has the scrollable content to have a property of `flex: 1 1 auto`; which is short-hand for `flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis`. This will make it use all the available space that remains on the page without actually increasing the size of it.

You can read more about flexbox here: [Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), its really worth it and will help a lot in building these kind of layouts easily without much CSS

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #000a34;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #FFCC66;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 4.8vmin;
  background: linear-gradient(#505050, #424242)
}

nav a {
  font-size: 2.9vmin;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #FF9C00;
}

.purpleheading {
  font-size: 5vmin;
  color: #9C9CFF;
  padding: 15px 0 0 30px;
  text-align: left;
}

footer {
  margin: 8px auto 0;
  background-color: #252525;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1em;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px black;
  border: solid 5px black;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px #9C9CFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid 5px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <a href="index.html">home</a>
      <a href="chapters.html">chapters</a>
      <a href="records.html">starfleet records</a>
      <a href="aboutme.html">about the author</a>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <section class="content">
    <h3 class="purpleheading">to boldly go where no man has gone before . . .</h3>
    <p class="hometext">Star Trek: Precious is a series set in the year 2409, approximately 30 years after the events of the film Star Trek: Nemesis. Following the crew of the U.S.S. Pureshashu where the Federation has entered a time of both relative peace but is also on
      the verge of war with the Klingdom Empire. The latter of which can no longer allow the Federation to maintain peace with the Romulan Empire due to their great distaste for the Romulans. But the Klingons are not the only nefarious individuals who
      seek to cause chaos and conflict throughout the known galaxy.</p>
    <p class="hometext">Both familiar enemies and new foes will test the Federation’s founding principles of peace and exploration in a time where Starfleet must hold onto these principles more than ever. The Starship Pureshashu, NCC-86521, a newer generation Vesta-class
      vessel was recently commissioned by Admiral J’Greed for his newly promoted son, Nathan Jenkins. Upon it’s departure for it’s maiden voyage which was to entail the pick-up of it’s exexcutive officer as part of a friendly agreement between the United
      Federation of Planets and the newly formed Romulan Republic, as well as end the voyage by returning to Deep Space Nine for it’s final crew members.</p>
    <p class="hometext">However this particular event in history begun a series of events that would lead the Pureshashu and it’s crew from one bad situation into another. During which time, the Klingdom Empire would begin to become more and more aggressive as the Federation
      and the Klingdom Empire would then soon enter all out war. Therefore for what would start out as a set of missions of a peaceful nature including the re-exploration of the Delta Quadrant would ultimately lead the Pureshashu and it’s crew into a
      deadly plot deeloping behind the scenes that may very well change the galaxy as everyone knows it, forever.</p>
  </section>

  <footer>
    <small>copyright &copy; ashworthian designs 2019 • all rights reserved • version one</small>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: @WarrenMitchell try again, beacause I just added most of the styles you provided along with mine and its working fine, check the edit... If something's not working it might be due to conflicting CSS on your sheet or wrong structure

Comment: @WarrenMitchell I removed the `img` tags since I don't have them, but you can add them back without issues; if you test the snippet in full screen and try resizing it you'll notice that it will never cause a scrollbar on the body, only on the `section` element

Comment: So I thought I had it, was looking perfect on my desktop. Viewed it on my laptop and it's back to not being the same.

Comment: Where is it not the same? On your local files or the snippet? The snippet should be working fine regardless on where you look at it... If its ocurring on the files on your laptop, there might be conflicting CSS

Comment: No the local files on my desktop is the same as the snippet, but my laptop (which has a smaller resolution to boot) is not and for some odd reason now my media query is broke too lol

Comment: Hmm.. okay, try reverting the changes first so you start from the beginning again... apply the changes carefully, I did notice your structure is pretty much the same I thought of when creating the firs example I made... First difference I found was that your `container` div didn't include the `footer`, in my case it does, so make sure that the footer is inside as well... I've tested this even on mobile phone resolutions and it works as it should

Comment: Yeah I had it outside of that because the container was applying the outline stroke to everything but the footer. But I changed the divs around so that's named something else.

Comment: It's hard to assist you since I'm not able to look at your code, I can only suggest looking carefully at the snippet and add the needed properties, making sure the structure is the same, and then try to delete one rule at a time to see when it breaks so you locate the issue... The important properties I included are `flex-direction: column` for the `container`, and `flex: 1 1 auto` for the `section`, the rest can be added without much issue

Comment: Yeah, that's how I have it set up. I did link the css and html files since that's the only way I know to show it.

Comment: Hey @WarrenMitchell I'm curious, were you able to fix the issue?

Comment: Alas, no. I eventually just got frustrated with it and gave up,