# Cannot make div fit a flex height

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I use mainly Bootstrap, but in this case nor pure CSS nor Bootstrap could make the case. I have an HTML like this:

```css
#filling{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center mt-3">
            <div class="col-6 text-center">
                <img width="150" height="150" src="img/user-placeholder.svg">
                <p class="mt-2 mb-0">pholder</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="mb-2">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6 text-center">pholder</div>
                        <div class="col-6 text-center">pholder</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6 text-center">Friends</div>
                        <div class="col-6 text-center">Posts</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <butto class="btn btn-transparent mt-2">Click</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <p class="text-center m-0">Contents</p>
        <hr class="mt-0 mb-2">
    </div>
    <div id="filling" class="text-center">
        <div class="sample">
             <img width="270" height="270" src="my_img.jpg">
             <p>coding</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sample">
             <img width="270" height="270" src="my_img.jpg">
             <p>coding</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sample">
             <img width="270" height="270" src="my_img.jpg">
             <p>coding</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Now the issue is: the #filling div has to be populated dynamically and I want it to behave like ListView in Android programming. I must be able to scroll it. Therefore I added some CSS:

```
#filling{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

But if I populate the div by appending children like those three .sample divs, the list grows vertically but the #filling div does too. In other words, its' forcing me to scroll the entire page rather than just the div.

I hope I have been clear, this sure will be marked as a duplicate of any flex question but I'd like to receive a working solution because other than fixing the height of the div, say, at 250px I cannot find a "responsive" way to do it.

Comment: First thing, change the = after flex-direction to a colon `flex-direction:column;`

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55753739/8437694) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55733093/8437694)... if you are using percentages to define a height, you need a parent with an explicit height set up, you can also use the `vh` unit to set the height with the viewport height

Answer (score 0):

I created a quick solution where I set the `max-heigth` of your `#filling div` to `50%.`
Please note, you need to set the height of all outer containers to 100% for this to work.

JSBin link: https://jsbin.com/nofobak/edit?html,css,output

```
<div id="my-container">
    <div class="container h-40">
        <div class="row align-items-center mt-3">
            <div class="col-6 text-center">
                <img width="150" height="150" src="img/user-placeholder.svg">
                <p class="mt-2 mb-0">pholder</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="mb-2">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6 text-center">pholder</div>
                        <div class="col-6 text-center">pholder</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6 text-center">Friends</div>
                        <div class="col-6 text-center">Posts</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <butto class="btn btn-transparent mt-2">Click</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <p class="text-center m-0">Contents</p>
        <hr class="mt-0 mb-2">
    </div>
    <div id="filling" class="h-60 text-center">
        <div class="sample">
             <img width="270" height="270" src="my_img.jpg">
             <p>coding</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sample">
             <img width="270" height="270" src="my_img.jpg">
             <p>coding</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sample">
             <img width="270" height="270" src="my_img.jpg">
             <p>coding</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


#filling{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 50%;
}

html {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

#my-container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things, `h-40` is not a Bootstrap class, unless you have it as a custom class you made; Bootstrap's height utility classes are just `h-25, h-50, h-75, h-100, h-auto`.

As mentioned in my comment and the answers linked, you if you want to use percentages, you need to have a parent with a fixed height so the percentage can take that as a reference; the other option is to use `vh` units to set the height relative to the viewport's height.

Bootstrap also provides some [utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/sizing/#relative-to-the-viewport) for this

Now you would need to take into account the headers content of course

```css
#posts_list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 60vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center mt-3">
      <div class="col-6 text-center">
        <img width="150" height="150" src="img/user-placeholder.svg">
        <p class="mt-2 mb-0">pholder</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="mb-2">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 text-center">pholder</div>
            <div class="col-6 text-center">pholder</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 text-center">Friends</div>
            <div class="col-6 text-center">Posts</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <butto class="btn btn-transparent mt-2">Click</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <p class="text-center m-0">Contents</p>
    <hr class="mt-0 mb-2">
  </div>
  <div id="posts_list" class="h-60 text-center">
    <div class="sample">
      <img width="270" height="270" src="my_img.jpg">
      <p>coding</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sample">
      <img width="270" height="270" src="my_img.jpg">
      <p>coding</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sample">
      <img width="270" height="270" src="my_img.jpg">
      <p>coding</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```